# How to install self signed certificate for Java in Docker/Kubernetes?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I am running a Spring Boot application in Docker with Kubernetes.

While downloading an image I am getting the below error:

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried adding the certificate to the docker image and installing them via keytool

Comment: @Lesiak :: Thanks.  I just installed certificate to the docker and it is working fine now

Comment: In this case, I'll post my advice as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the certificates to the docker image and installing them via keytool

Answer (score 1):

After adding certificate to the docker now i am able to access the remote site.

Assure I need to download files  or access abc.com over https

Add below lines to your Docker file

```
 USER root
 RUN cd $JAVA_HOME/lib/security && echo -n | openssl s_client -connect abc.com:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > abc.com.crt &&  keytool -keystore cacerts -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -noprompt -import -v -trustcacerts -alias abc.com -file abc.com.crt
```